# Can I replace Video with VLC Media Player?

Tags: 19.04, video-player

I want to have VLC Media Player as my default video player.

I don't like having an unused app that has more 1-stars than 5-stars on my computer. I wanted to know if anything would happen if I uninstalled the default video player (Video) for Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: You don't need to uninstall and you can make any other media player the default one.

Comment: The only thing to happen would be you have one less choice of video players.  Do not think it would make enough of a difference if it was uninstalled, unless you really needed the space, then you have bigger problems anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a problem if you uninstalled the default video player.
You can however set vlc as default player from **Settings** > **Details** > **Default Applications**

[image: Settings]